# Logaritmic equation with floor brackets $ \left \lfloor \frac{x-1}{2} -\left \lfloor \frac{x}{2} \right \rfloor \right \rfloor=\log_{10}x$

Tags: logarithms, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Solve equation

$ \left \lfloor \frac{x-1}{2} -\left \lfloor \frac{x}{2} \right \rfloor \right \rfloor= \log_{10}x$

I dont understand solution explained in the book.

$ \left \lfloor \frac{x-1}{2} -\left \lfloor \frac{x}{2} \right \rfloor \right \rfloor= \left \lfloor \frac{x}{2}- \left \lfloor \frac{x}{2} \right \rfloor -\frac{1}{2} \right \rfloor=\left \lfloor \left \{ \frac{x}{2} \right \}-\frac{1}{2} \right \rfloor$

I dont understand why is

$\left \lfloor \frac{x}{2}- \left \lfloor \frac{x}{2} \right \rfloor -\frac{1}{2} \right \rfloor=\left \lfloor \left \{ \frac{x}{2} \right \}-\frac{1}{2} \right \rfloor$

Comment: For real number $r, \{r\}$ is the fractional part of $r$ and $\lfloor r\rfloor$ is the largest integer $\leq r$.  For example $r = \frac{15}{4}$ has $\{r\} = \frac{3}{4}$ and $\lfloor r\rfloor = 3.$  In general, $r = \lfloor r\rfloor + \{r\}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\{x\}$, the fractional part of x, is defined as $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x\rfloor$. (For example, $\{3.14\} = 0.14$, $\{-0.6\} = 0.4$, $\{1\} = 0$, etc. Thus, $\boxed{\frac{x}{2}-\left\lfloor\frac{x}{2}\right\rfloor = \bigg\{\frac{x}{2}\bigg\}.}$